# Time round to the nearest hour

Tags: javascript

I Have a string which represent time.
For example let's take this string:

```
var s = '06:59'
```

how to round time to the nearest hour?

Comment: `100/60*min` can give you real decimal so 59min becomes `98.33333333333334`

Comment: i can do it like creating new date than getting minutes rounding it than again converting to the string format but it's to big code so i am trying to do it elegant way

Comment: Can you please post that big code? Maybe we find some simplifications. But it seems to be the correct approach (assuming that time needs to be stored as string, which might be the actual issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
var s = '06:59';
var n = s.split(':');
n[0] = Math.round( parseInt(n[0]) + parseInt(n[1])/60 ) % 24;
n[1] = '00';
var output = n.join(':');
```

Or more concisely as suggested by [N20084753](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1571610/n20084753),

```
var s = '06:59';
var n = s.split(':');
var output = Math.round( parseInt(n[0]) + parseInt(n[1])/60 ) % 24 + ':00';
```

Comment: very nice solution, adding to it a bit 

var output = Math.round( parseInt(n[0]) + parseInt(n[1])/60 ) + ':00';

I think there is no need for join.

Comment: be careful with times like `23:59` though, you might not want your output to be `24:00`

Comment: @AndrewCounts Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my ans with `%24` to take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mins = parseInt(s.split(":")[1]);
var hours = parseInt(s.split(":")[0]);
var result = "";
if(mins > 30)
   hours++;
if(hours < 10)
  result = "0" + hours + ":00";
else if(hours > 23)
  result = "00:00";
else
  result = "" + hours + ":00";
```

Comment: This is JavaScript, so there's no `(int)` typecasting (use the [`parseInt` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for that), and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is spelled lowercase.

Comment: Its simply `parseInt` no namespace and remember the radix 10

Answer (score 0):

```
var roundTime = function(time) { 
    var splitted = time.split(':');
    var mins  = parseInt(splitted[1]),
        hours = parseInt(splitted[0]);
    return (mins > 31 ? hours + 1 : hours ) + ":00";
 }
```